# Fortran 77 compilation for IRI 2016 model

Tags: fortran, gfortran, fortran77

I've been trying to compile the [IRI model lately](http://irimodel.org/), somewhat unsuccessfully. I've downloaded the IRI 2016 + common files + indices files, and using the test file to, well, test. I'm using gfortran (though the code is in fortran 77) with the -std=legacy flag (to remove unnecessary warnings, but I think the code is compiled as fortran 2003 or something). The linking/compilation command I'm using is:

```
gfortran -std=legacy -o iri iritest.for irisub.for irifun.for iritec.for iridreg.for igrf.for cira.for iriflip.for
```

This gives me the `iri.exe` executable, and yields a few warnings of the form:

```
Warning: Array reference at (1) out of bounds in loop beginning at (2)
```

(at compile time).

When I run the executable and enter the inputs through the console, I'm getting the following flags:

```
Note: The following floating-point exceptions are signalling: IEEE_UNDERFLOW_FLAG IEEE_DENORMAL
```

and the code apparently does what it's supposed to (outputs a nonempty file named `fort.7` with the results). I've read that the IEEE flags I'm getting are rather common, and that I can disregard them, but the out of range warnings are a bit more concerning to me.
I'm also getting the following warnings:

```
igrf.for:298:10:

  296 |       DO 3 N=3,3333
      |                                                                        2
  297 | C*****CORRECTOR (FIELD LINE TRACING)
  298 |       P(1,N)=P(1,N-1)+STEP12*(5.*P(4,N)+8.*P(4,N-1)-P(4,N-2))
      |          1
Warning: Array reference at (1) out of bounds (3333 > 100) in loop beginning at (2)
igrf.for:298:17:

  296 |       DO 3 N=3,3333
      |                                                                        2
  297 | C*****CORRECTOR (FIELD LINE TRACING)
  298 |       P(1,N)=P(1,N-1)+STEP12*(5.*P(4,N)+8.*P(4,N-1)-P(4,N-2))
      |                 1
Warning: Array reference at (1) out of bounds (3332 > 100) in loop beginning at (2)
igrf.for:298:37:

  296 |       DO 3 N=3,3333
      |                                                                        2
  297 | C*****CORRECTOR (FIELD LINE TRACING)
  298 |       P(1,N)=P(1,N-1)+STEP12*(5.*P(4,N)+8.*P(4,N-1)-P(4,N-2))
      |                                     1
Warning: Array reference at (1) out of bounds (3333 > 100) in loop beginning at (2)
igrf.for:298:47:

  296 |       DO 3 N=3,3333
      |                                                                        2
  297 | C*****CORRECTOR (FIELD LINE TRACING)
  298 |       P(1,N)=P(1,N-1)+STEP12*(5.*P(4,N)+8.*P(4,N-1)-P(4,N-2))
      |                                               1
Warning: Array reference at (1) out of bounds (3332 > 100) in loop beginning at (2)
igrf.for:298:56:

  296 |       DO 3 N=3,3333
      |                                                                        2
  297 | C*****CORRECTOR (FIELD LINE TRACING)
  298 |       P(1,N)=P(1,N-1)+STEP12*(5.*P(4,N)+8.*P(4,N-1)-P(4,N-2))
      |                                                        1
Warning: Array reference at (1) out of bounds (3331 > 100) in loop beginning at (2)
igrf.for:299:10:

  296 |       DO 3 N=3,3333
      |                                                                        2
......
  299 |       P(2,N)=P(2,N-1)+STEP12*(5.*P(5,N)+8.*P(5,N-1)-P(5,N-2))
      |          1
Warning: Array reference at (1) out of bounds (3333 > 100) in loop beginning at (2)
igrf.for:299:17:

  296 |       DO 3 N=3,3333
      |                                                                        2
......
  299 |       P(2,N)=P(2,N-1)+STEP12*(5.*P(5,N)+8.*P(5,N-1)-P(5,N-2))
      |                 1
Warning: Array reference at (1) out of bounds (3332 > 100) in loop beginning at (2)
igrf.for:299:37:

  296 |       DO 3 N=3,3333
      |                                                                        2
......
  299 |       P(2,N)=P(2,N-1)+STEP12*(5.*P(5,N)+8.*P(5,N-1)-P(5,N-2))
      |                                     1
Warning: Array reference at (1) out of bounds (3333 > 100) in loop beginning at (2)
igrf.for:299:47:

  296 |       DO 3 N=3,3333
      |                                                                        2
......
  299 |       P(2,N)=P(2,N-1)+STEP12*(5.*P(5,N)+8.*P(5,N-1)-P(5,N-2))
      |                                               1
Warning: Array reference at (1) out of bounds (3332 > 100) in loop beginning at (2)
igrf.for:299:56:

  296 |       DO 3 N=3,3333
      |                                                                        2
......
  299 |       P(2,N)=P(2,N-1)+STEP12*(5.*P(5,N)+8.*P(5,N-1)-P(5,N-2))
      |                                                        1
Warning: Array reference at (1) out of bounds (3331 > 100) in loop beginning at (2)
igrf.for:302:10:

  296 |       DO 3 N=3,3333
      |                                                                        2
......
  302 |       P(8,N)=STEP2*(P(1,N)*P(4,N)+P(2,N)*P(5,N))
      |          1
Warning: Array reference at (1) out of bounds (3333 > 100) in loop beginning at (2)
igrf.for:302:24:

  296 |       DO 3 N=3,3333
      |                                                                        2
......
  302 |       P(8,N)=STEP2*(P(1,N)*P(4,N)+P(2,N)*P(5,N))
      |                        1
Warning: Array reference at (1) out of bounds (3333 > 100) in loop beginning at (2)
igrf.for:302:31:

  296 |       DO 3 N=3,3333
      |                                                                        2
......
  302 |       P(8,N)=STEP2*(P(1,N)*P(4,N)+P(2,N)*P(5,N))
      |                               1
Warning: Array reference at (1) out of bounds (3333 > 100) in loop beginning at (2)
igrf.for:302:38:

  296 |       DO 3 N=3,3333
      |                                                                        2
......
  302 |       P(8,N)=STEP2*(P(1,N)*P(4,N)+P(2,N)*P(5,N))
      |                                      1
Warning: Array reference at (1) out of bounds (3333 > 100) in loop beginning at (2)
igrf.for:302:45:

  296 |       DO 3 N=3,3333
      |                                                                        2
......
  302 |       P(8,N)=STEP2*(P(1,N)*P(4,N)+P(2,N)*P(5,N))
      |                                             1
Warning: Array reference at (1) out of bounds (3333 > 100) in loop beginning at (2)
igrf.for:303:13:

  296 |       DO 3 N=3,3333
      |                                                                        2
......
  303 |       C0=P(1,N-1)**2+P(2,N-1)**2
      |             1
Warning: Array reference at (1) out of bounds (3332 > 100) in loop beginning at (2)
igrf.for:303:25:

  296 |       DO 3 N=3,3333
      |                                                                        2
......
  303 |       C0=P(1,N-1)**2+P(2,N-1)**2
      |                         1
Warning: Array reference at (1) out of bounds (3332 > 100) in loop beginning at (2)
igrf.for:304:13:

  296 |       DO 3 N=3,3333
      |                                                                        2
......
  304 |       C1=P(8,N-1)
      |             1
Warning: Array reference at (1) out of bounds (3332 > 100) in loop beginning at (2)
igrf.for:305:14:

  296 |       DO 3 N=3,3333
      |                                                                        2
......
  305 |       C2=(P(8,N)-P(8,N-2))*0.25
      |              1
Warning: Array reference at (1) out of bounds (3333 > 100) in loop beginning at (2)
igrf.for:305:21:

  296 |       DO 3 N=3,3333
      |                                                                        2
......
  305 |       C2=(P(8,N)-P(8,N-2))*0.25
      |                     1
Warning: Array reference at (1) out of bounds (3331 > 100) in loop beginning at (2)
igrf.for:306:14:

  296 |       DO 3 N=3,3333
      |                                                                        2
......
  306 |       C3=(P(8,N)+P(8,N-2)-C1-C1)/6.0
      |              1
Warning: Array reference at (1) out of bounds (3333 > 100) in loop beginning at (2)
igrf.for:306:21:

  296 |       DO 3 N=3,3333
      |                                                                        2
......
  306 |       C3=(P(8,N)+P(8,N-2)-C1-C1)/6.0
      |                     1
Warning: Array reference at (1) out of bounds (3331 > 100) in loop beginning at (2)
igrf.for:307:13:

  296 |       DO 3 N=3,3333
      |                                                                        2
......
  307 |       D0=P(6,N-1)
      |             1
Warning: Array reference at (1) out of bounds (3332 > 100) in loop beginning at (2)
igrf.for:308:14:

  296 |       DO 3 N=3,3333
      |                                                                        2
......
  308 |       D1=(P(6,N)-P(6,N-2))*0.5
      |              1
Warning: Array reference at (1) out of bounds (3333 > 100) in loop beginning at (2)
igrf.for:308:21:

  296 |       DO 3 N=3,3333
      |                                                                        2
......
  308 |       D1=(P(6,N)-P(6,N-2))*0.5
      |                     1
Warning: Array reference at (1) out of bounds (3331 > 100) in loop beginning at (2)
igrf.for:309:14:

  296 |       DO 3 N=3,3333
      |                                                                        2
......
  309 |       D2=(P(6,N)+P(6,N-2)-D0-D0)*0.5
      |              1
Warning: Array reference at (1) out of bounds (3333 > 100) in loop beginning at (2)
igrf.for:309:21:

  296 |       DO 3 N=3,3333
      |                                                                        2
......
  309 |       D2=(P(6,N)+P(6,N-2)-D0-D0)*0.5
      |                     1
Warning: Array reference at (1) out of bounds (3331 > 100) in loop beginning at (2)
igrf.for:310:13:

  296 |       DO 3 N=3,3333
      |                                                                        2
......
  310 |       E0=P(7,N-1)
      |             1
Warning: Array reference at (1) out of bounds (3332 > 100) in loop beginning at (2)
igrf.for:311:14:

  296 |       DO 3 N=3,3333
      |                                                                        2
......
  311 |       E1=(P(7,N)-P(7,N-2))*0.5
      |              1
Warning: Array reference at (1) out of bounds (3333 > 100) in loop beginning at (2)
igrf.for:311:21:

  296 |       DO 3 N=3,3333
      |                                                                        2
......
  311 |       E1=(P(7,N)-P(7,N-2))*0.5
      |                     1
Warning: Array reference at (1) out of bounds (3331 > 100) in loop beginning at (2)
igrf.for:312:14:

  296 |       DO 3 N=3,3333
      |                                                                        2
......
  312 |       E2=(P(7,N)+P(7,N-2)-E0-E0)*0.5
      |              1
Warning: Array reference at (1) out of bounds (3333 > 100) in loop beginning at (2)
igrf.for:312:21:

  296 |       DO 3 N=3,3333
      |                                                                        2
......
  312 |       E2=(P(7,N)+P(7,N-2)-E0-E0)*0.5
      |                     1
Warning: Array reference at (1) out of bounds (3331 > 100) in loop beginning at (2)
igrf.for:314:15:

  296 |       DO 3 N=3,3333
      |                                                                        2
......
  314 | 4     T=(Z-P(3,N-1))/STEP
      |               1
Warning: Array reference at (1) out of bounds (3332 > 100) in loop beginning at (2)
```

This is what I'm getting with `gfortran` compiler. I don't get any when using the Intel Fortran compiler.

Now, when I'm trying to compile the same model with a custom script instead of the test script in `iritest.for`, I get the same out of range warnings at compile time and a few errors at runtime, as well as a `fort.7` file containing only -1s (which is the value for "no value/result"). The errors/flags at runtime are:

```
Note: The following floating-point exceptions are signalling: IEEE_INVALID_FLAG
```

and

```
201301** OUT OF RANGE **
     The file IG_RZ.DAT which contains the indices Rz12 and IG12
     currently only covers the time period (yymm) :      0-     0
```

In that custom script I'm only calling the subroutine `IRI_SUB` present in the `irisub.for` file, with inputs declared within the script+read from a text file. I've made sure to include the lines that are mandatory to include (see `iritest.for`). The inputs from the text file are indeed read (verified with a few `WRITE`). I know the custom script worked at some point in time because it's from a thesis made in the laboratory I'm currently working for. I've run out of ideas as of what I can try to debug this. I've tried the same with IRI 2012 and I'm getting the exact same flags/warnings/errors. Has anyone any idea of what I can try next?

EDIT: I've been able to get the custom script to yield results, but I'm not sure they are the right ones, since I've used the Intel Fortran compiler (and this one does not give me any warning anymore).

Comment: Certainly completely disregard the `Note: The following floating-point exceptions...`. It is just noise caused by the `STOP` statements. I do not like the code. It is really old-style, but also mixes spaces and TABs in fixed form.

Comment: You must show the **complete** error output. See [ask] and [mcve]. The compiler surely shows the location of those warnings. Not "a few warnings of the form" but actual complete warnings.

Comment: Other than that, you will have to locate the code location, where "201301** OUT OF RANGE **" is printed and backtrack. Certainly check those indexes in the mentioned input data file.

Comment: I am sure I have downloaded this, so I’ll try and check.

Comment: @VladimirF Complete error output was 13 times the warning I got at specific lines pointing to the igrf.for file + I switched to Intel compiler and this apparently solved my issue!

Comment: @ChloéBenz The point is that you should really show exactly those specific lines. Please read those link that explain why the complete output us important.  The specific lines indicated are extremely important. Be aware that the change of the compiler probably just hides the issue. The program might be broken and produce incorrect results.

Comment: @VladimirF I've updated the main post with the actual warning messages

Comment: Something very dodgy is happening here, probably, the programmer is lying to the compiler about the actual array size. However, they are just warnings, not errors. Intel probably just chooses to not display them (however, please do try `ifort -warn -check`). What I did not get is whether you did get the `OUT OF RANGE` message also with ifort or you did not. We would need a clarification about that. But it is suspicious.

Comment: Having had a poke around `igrf.for`, it's possible all the `3333 > 100` warnings might be okay. There's a lot of `goto` in the loop, so `N` might never get larger than `100` as the loop might be escaped before then. The author might just have used `3333` as "a big number which will never be reached". If true, that's bad programming practice and I wouldn't like to rely on it.

Comment: @VladimirF I never got the out of range message with ifort. I'll try compiling with the flag you suggested!

Comment: That is strange. Two Fortran compilers should.normally not give different results. With the exception of floating point rounding errors.